# How to calculate time complexity of DFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Like the function below, how to calculate its time complexity? I think it's should be O(m*n)...

```
int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
    if (m < 1 || n < 1) return 0;     
    if (m == 1 && n == 1) return 1;      
    return uniquePaths(m - 1, n) + uniquePaths(m, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Well, how many unique paths are there?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Does it matter? 
From a mathematical point of view, it should be Combination(m+n, n)

Comment: Of course it matters - you're visiting all of them, right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok, I get it...

Comment: In the real world, you would memoize the values of `uniquePaths(m, n)` to save a ton of time recalculating values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model the time complexity with the recursive function `T(m,n) = T(m-1, n) + T(m, n-1)`, where `T(1,1)=1` and `T(m,n)=0` whenever `min(m,n)<1`.

It looks like `T(m,n)=(m+n choose m)`. To see this note that `(m+n choose n) = (m+n-1 choose m) + (m+n-1 choose m-1)` by the [recurrence for the binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula), and that `T(m,n) = T(m-1, n) + T(m,n-1)` is exactly the same recurrence.

Thus `T(m,n) = O((m+n)^n / n!)`. (There are [many other bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas).)

Answer (score 1):

### The Recursion Tree:

To represent a problem with m = M and n = N, let's write it as *`<M, N>`*. If we try to draw the recursion tree of this problem:

- At root, we have one problem: *`<M, N>`*
- Then, root breaks to two problems: *`<M-1, N>`* and *`<M, N-1>`*
- And, if we continue down this recursion tree, we will reach to leaves, which will be *`<0, 0>`*.

---

### Tree's Depth:

But, what is the maximum depth possible for this tree? It's <sup><sup>*1*</sup></sup>(M + N). Further, *each node `<M, N>` can break to at most 2 paths, viz. `<M-1, N>` and `<M, N-1>`.*

---

### Inferring Complexity From Tree:

So, what is the maximum number of leaves possible? (Hint: 2<sup>(M + N)</sup>)

Well, since every node breaks to two nodes, at every level, the number of leaves will be multiplied by 2, starting from 1 at the root.

- So, starting from root, total leaves possible = 2<sup>(M + N - 1)</sup>.
- Multiplying and dividing by 2 gives us, (1 / 2) * 2<sup>(M + N)</sup>
- Getting rid of the constant value (1 / 2) gives us the complexity = 2<sup>(M + N)</sup> !

---

**Hence, the complexity of your algorithm can be upper bounded to *O(2<sup>(m + n)</sup>).***

---

*<sup><sup>1</sup>The longest path will start from `<M, N>` and first go to `<0, N>`. Then from there it will go to `<0, 0>`. So, longest possible path length = M + N.</sup>*